# Should I really implement IDisposable in this case?

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, idisposable

I'm currently using NDepend while developping a C# application. I get a violation on a rule stating that "Types with disposable instance fields must be disposable".

I know you should in fact do that when you do something like this:

```
class SomeClass : IDisposable
{
    private Control _someControl; // implements IDisposable

    public SomeClass()
    {
        _someControl = new RandomControl();
    }

    // ...
}
```

However, I get the violation in a handler class like this:

```
public class SomeHandler
{
    private Control _someControl; // implements IDisposable

    public SomeHandler(Control control)
    {
        _someControl = control;
    }

    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        DoSomethingWith(_someControl);
    }

    // ...
}
```

The handler object is supposed to live exactly as long as the control. Should I really implement IDisposable in this case? In all cases, the handler class should not be responsible for disposing the stored control (but instead the class which created the control in the first place).

Comment: The important question is who owns the disposable object. Is it given to `SomeHandler` to own, or just to reference? If the first, then yes, you should implement IDisposable. If the latter, then no.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't have ownership of the "object" you mustn't dispose it.

There are some classes (like `StreamReader` for example) that have a configuration option to tell if they should take ownership of the `Stream` you pass them. Clearly `StreamReader` must be `IDisposable` and do some logic check

For example: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/gg712952.aspx

```
public StreamReader(
    Stream stream,
    Encoding encoding,
    bool detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks,
    int bufferSize,
    bool leaveOpen
)
```

Something more similar: the [PictureBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox.aspx) class doesn't take ownership of the `Image` passed. The `Image` must be disposed by the creator/owner of the control and/or if you replace an `Image` with another `Image`, (setting the property `Image`) by the one that does the operation.

Note that in C# there is no way to know if a control should take/has ownership of something or not. You can only write it in documentation.

Comment: Agreed,  "having a field of type X" is often mistaken for "having ownership over an instance of type X".

Comment: @xanatos Thanks for the quick reply. Should I still Implement IDisposable and set `_someControl` to `null` maybe?

Comment: @TimMeyer This is a good question... I don't have an anwer :-) In general, if your object is only an handler, then probably you shouldn't... By having a `IDisposable` you are telling the world "I have something that I need disposing"... But you don't have something that needs disposing :-)

Comment: It's too bad that there's no standard convention by which things like `PictureBox` can be told whether they should take ownership of an image, since that in turn means that code wanting to change what a `PictureBox` is showing will in general have no way of knowing whether it holds the only reference to an image that exists solely for its benefit (which should thus be disposed when it's replaced), or a reference to a shared image which other will still need even if the picture box doesn't.